# speed up replication of rows using model

Tags: r

I would like to create replicate predictions for one integer independent variable (iv1) given some model and a data frame called training. This is my current approach. I appreciate this is not self containing but hopefully it is self explanatory:

```
number_of_samples <- 10
results <- NULL
for (row in 1:nrow(training)) {

    fake_iv1_values <- sample(1:100, number_of_samples)
    case <- training[row,]

    for (iv1 in fake_iv1_values) {
        case$iv1 <- iv1

        case$prediction <- predict(some_model, newdata = case)

        results <- rbind(results, case)
    }
}
```

Using loops is very slow. I wonder, if this could be sped up? Thanks!

Comment: I think you can do `predict(some_model, newdata = fake_iv1_values)` directly. In R many functions a vectorized. But if you share an example of `training` and `fake_iv1_values` is should be easier to test it.

Comment: @Edo - this would not work as there are other independent values but I think I could create a data frame of replicated cases first and the use the model in one sweep and append the predictions.

Comment: can i assume that `training` and `some_model` look as follow? `training <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), iv1 = rnorm(100)); some_model <- lm(y~x+iv1, training)`

Comment: yep but more xs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

Reproducible fake data and model:

```
# create fake data
n_row <- 100
n_xs  <- 100

training <- data.frame(y = rnorm(n_row), iv1 = rnorm(n_row))
training[, paste0("x",1:n_xs)] <- replicate(n_xs, list(rnorm(n_row)))

# example model
some_model <- lm(y~., training)
```

Rewritten code:

```
number_of_samples <- 10
results <- NULL

# vector of several fake_iv1_values vectors
fake_iv1_values <- as.numeric(replicate(nrow(training), sample(1:100, number_of_samples)))

# replicate each row of the original dataframe
results <- training[rep(seq_len(nrow(training)), each = number_of_samples), ]

# add fake values to the replicated dataframe
results$iv1 <- fake_iv1_values

# get predictions
results$prediction <- predict(some_model, newdata = results)
```